# Can someone explain how <authentication mode="None" /> affect my ASP.net MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

At first i totally could't use Roles and Authorization function at all, or `User.IsInRole("Admin")` function to check current user's role to be specific. It was always return an error in debug said the server cannot connect to SQL Database. I can connect to database normally, login logout register all works fine, i still can add roles into database. I only could't get current user roles .

I came to a lucky solution by just remove this code:

```
    <authentication mode="None" />
```

from 
 `<system.web>`tag in **Web.config** file and it fix my problem. I just want to know what happen? how did it work? And is there other modes of authentication  that i should use?